# Calculating zonal statistics as table for all attributes (columns) in raster using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have a raster that has multiple columns in the attribute table that I can symbolize. I would like to calculate zonal statistics as a table for each of the columns in the raster attribute table individually.

How do I do this?

Here is an example of the raster attribute table.

| OID | Value | Count | slodegradd | aws025wta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 538236 | 7729 | 0.5 | 0.3 |
| 1 | 538237 | 21 | 0.4 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 538239 | 82 | 0.5 | 0.3 |

Comment: Rasters don't normally have columns in attribute tables. Do you have one dataset or two? I know that rasters can have attribute tables, but they normally apply to the raster as a whole, whereas what you are doing sounds like something you would do with vector features.

Comment: Yes, this is confusing to me also but when I open the raster attribute table, it has multiple columns. The raster is from the SSURGO soils geodatabase so maybe that is why?

Comment: What do the rows in the raster attribute table represent?

Comment: When I select an individual row, multiple pixels are highlighted. The rows represent object Ids "OID" (0-68), each with values (column 2), counts (column 3) and then the other columns are the attributes I am interested in.

Comment: What kind of file format is the raster? Geotiff?

Comment: It says "TIFF" under Raster Information in Properties --> Source

Comment: Is it associated with a shape file? Soil website mentions shape files and tables. If so, maybe you can just use the shape file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using the 'Lookup' and then 'Zonal Statistics as Table'.